# Remove transformation is not working for a column

Tags: symmetricds

I am trying out a scenario where tables of two databases in MySQL are synchronized and in some places, columns are transformed. I have a perticular case where every column of DB1 table while insertion, will be synchronized (a new row will be inserted in DB2) but for updating that row, a specific column will have no effect on DB2 table (every other column will be updated). I am trying to achieve this by 'remove transformation' ([one of the transformation types](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_transform_types)). But my remove transformation is not working. Other transformations are working fine. May be I have missed a thing. A little help will be much appreciated.

DB1: records_new Table: employee

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(11) DEFAULT 'Mr.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

DB2: records_new_replica Table: employee

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////sym tables//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

sym_node_group

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_node_group
(node_group_id, description, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time)
VALUES('records', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO records.sym_node_group
(node_group_id, description, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time)
VALUES('records-replica', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

sym_node

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_node
(node_id, node_group_id, external_id, sync_enabled, sync_url, schema_version, symmetric_version, config_version, database_type, database_version, batch_to_send_count, batch_in_error_count, created_at_node_id, deployment_type, deployment_sub_type)
VALUES('000', 'records', '000', 1, 'http://localhost:31415/sync/records-000', '?', '3.10.4', '3.10.4', 'MySQL', '8.0', -1, -1, NULL, 'server', NULL);
INSERT INTO records.sym_node
(node_id, node_group_id, external_id, sync_enabled, sync_url, schema_version, symmetric_version, config_version, database_type, database_version, batch_to_send_count, batch_in_error_count, created_at_node_id, deployment_type, deployment_sub_type)
VALUES('2000', 'records-replica', '2000', 1, 'http://DESKTOP-KSP9CJD:31415/sync/records-replica-1000', '?', '3.10.4', '3.10.4', 'MySQL', '8.0', -1, -1, '000', 'server', NULL);
```

sym_router

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_router
(router_id, target_catalog_name, target_schema_name, target_table_name, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, router_type, router_expression, sync_on_update, sync_on_insert, sync_on_delete, use_source_catalog_schema, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-new', '', '', '', 'records', 'records-replica', 'default', '', 1, 1, 0, 1, '2019-10-30 09:40:25', NULL, '2019-10-30 09:40:25', '');
```

sym_trigger

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_trigger
(trigger_id, source_catalog_name, source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, reload_channel_id, sync_on_update, sync_on_insert, sync_on_delete, sync_on_incoming_batch, name_for_update_trigger, name_for_insert_trigger, name_for_delete_trigger, sync_on_update_condition, sync_on_insert_condition, sync_on_delete_condition, custom_before_update_text, custom_before_insert_text, custom_before_delete_text, custom_on_update_text, custom_on_insert_text, custom_on_delete_text, external_select, tx_id_expression, channel_expression, excluded_column_names, included_column_names, sync_key_names, use_stream_lobs, use_capture_lobs, use_capture_old_data, use_handle_key_updates, stream_row, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-trig_new', 'records_new', '', 'employee', 'employee', 'reload', 1, 1, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, '2019-10-30 09:38:56', NULL, '2019-10-30 09:38:56', '');
```

sym_trigger_router

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_trigger_router
(trigger_id, router_id, enabled, initial_load_order, initial_load_select, initial_load_delete_stmt, ping_back_enabled, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-trig_new', 'emp-2-emp-new', 1, 1, '', '', 0, '2019-10-30 09:41:31', NULL, '2019-10-30 09:41:31', '');
```

sym_transform_table

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_transform_table
(transform_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, transform_point, source_catalog_name, source_schema_name, source_table_name, target_catalog_name, target_schema_name, target_table_name, update_first, update_action, delete_action, transform_order, column_policy, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-new', 'records', 'records-replica', 'LOAD', 'records_new', NULL, 'employee', 'records_new_replica', NULL, 'employee', 0, 'UPDATE_COL', 'NONE', 1, 'IMPLIED', '2019-10-30 11:38:22', NULL, '2019-10-30 11:38:22', '');
```

sym_transform_column

```
INSERT INTO records.sym_transform_column
(transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk, transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-new', '*', 'emp_name', 'name', 0, 'copy', '', 1, '2019-10-30 11:38:49', NULL, '2019-10-30 11:38:49', '');
INSERT INTO records.sym_transform_column
(transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk, transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-new', '*', 'time', NULL, 0, 'lookup', 'select UNIX_TIMESTAMP()', 1, '2019-10-31 10:01:02', NULL, '2019-10-31 10:01:02', '');
INSERT INTO records.sym_transform_column
(transform_id, include_on, target_column_name, source_column_name, pk, transform_type, transform_expression, transform_order, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description)
VALUES('emp-2-emp-new', 'U', 'title', 'title', 0, 'remove', '', 1, '2019-11-06 13:20:21', '', '2019-11-06 13:20:21', '');
```

Thanks in advance.:)

Answer (score 0):

**I wanted to delete this question. But i figured that may be...if someone stumbled upon symmetricds and after reading the user guide..missed a corner and that  became a doom for him...only for those...here it goes:**

In the guide, when describing fields of [sym_router](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_routers) table, it is stated about the *Use Source Catalog/Schema* field that

> If set then the source catalog and source schema are sent to the target to be used to find the target table.

and in [appendix/ROUTER](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_router) it is stated about *USE_SOURCE_CATALOG_SCHEMA* that,

> Whether or not to assume that the target catalog/schema name should be the same as the source catalog/schema name. The target catalog or schema name will still override if not blank.

Now lets see what might override those target variables. In [Transform](https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_transforms) section, they have stated the following:

> **Source Catalog**
>   Name of the catalog of the configured source table. *This should only be set* if Use Source Catalog/Schema or Target Catalog are set on the Router.
>
> **Source Schema**
>   Name of the schema for the configured source table. *This should only be set* if Use Source Catalog/Schema or Target Schema are set on the Router.

So, the resolution is, when I have set the source_catalog_name in sym_transform_table, then I have to set the use_source_catalog_schema in sym_router table and as my tables which I intended to sync is not in the default catalog then I have to explicitly set the other two columns e.g. target_catalog_name and target_table_name in sym_transform_table.

**tl;dr,** set the use_source_catalog_schema in table sym_router to 1 if source_catalog_name is set in the sym_transform_table for transformation and another thing...read the guide.it's brief but it's our only friend.